# EPPlus isn't honoring ExcelHorizontalAlignment Center or Right

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I've tried this in EPPlus versions 3.1.3.0 and the latest 4.0.4.0 and both are exhibiting the same behavior.

I'm trying to Center align text in cells but it's just not working. Numbers in cells work fine, strings do not. Following is an example of code that fails to produce the desired ExcelHorizontalAlignment:

```
var newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\sample.xlsx");
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");

    workSheet.Column(1).Width = 50;

    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "This should be left-aligned";
    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;


    workSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "This should be center-aligned";
    workSheet.Cells["A2"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;      // <- This  doesn't work.

    workSheet.Cells["A3"].RichText.Add("This should be center-aligned");
    workSheet.Cells["A3"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;      // <- This  doesn't work.


    workSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "This should be right-aligned";
    workSheet.Cells["A4"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;       // <- This  doesn't work.

    workSheet.Cells["A5"].RichText.Add("This should be right-aligned");
    workSheet.Cells["A5"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;       // <- This  doesn't work.


    //workSheet.Cells["A2:A3"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center; // <- This  doesn't work.
    //workSheet.Cells["A4:A5"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center; // <- This  doesn't work.

    package.Save();
}
```

It's making me a little  crazy. Any ideas why strings cannot be aligned?

Comment: This works perfectly as is for me.

Comment: What version did you test on? I took the output file and read it back in with EPPlus and it did indeed NOT show the alignment as Centered. I do have a solution which I will post later.

Comment: interesting! I used the most recent version (4.0.4) and just literally copied and pasted your own code. Yeah - let me know when you have posted the solution and I will have a look. Any chance that you don't have write permissions on that file or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though LibreOffice is partially at fault. If I generate the file with EPPlus, and open it in Calc, the Center and Right alignment is not displayed. If I then open the file in EPPlus, the formatting is General.

If, however, I generate the file using EPPlus and immediately read it in EPPlus, the alignment is as specified.

I do have a solution that works in Calc and Excel. If I create a NamedStyle, and apply it to cells or cell-ranges, everything works as expected.

```
var newFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");

    workSheet.Column(1).Width = 50;

    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "This should be left-aligned";
    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;

    var centerStyle = package.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("Center");
    centerStyle.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

    workSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "This should be center-aligned";
    workSheet.Cells["A3"].RichText.Add("This should be center-aligned");
    workSheet.Cells["A2:A3"].StyleName = "Center";

    var rightStyle = package.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("Right");
    rightStyle.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;

    workSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "This should be right-aligned";
    workSheet.Cells["A5"].RichText.Add("This should be right-aligned");
    workSheet.Cells["A4:A5"].StyleName = "Right";

    package.Save();
}
```